# Specific Error Catch in BlueBird promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using bluebird promise and standard-error. Issue is when i throw error like this

```
   return new PromiseReturns(function (resolve, reject) {
        reject(new StandardError({
        status: 'Error',
        message: "Not Found",
        originalError: err,
        code: 404
       }));
    });
```

it doesn't recieved in this catch

```
.catch(StandardError , function(err){
 })
```

instead its recieved in

```
.catch(function(err){
})
```

Comment: @JaromandaX bluebird allows you to catch specific error

Comment: See my update code

Comment: `new PromiseReturns` ??? If you meant `new Promise` really you should just `return Promise.reject( ... );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new PromiseReturns each time was causing the issue. I have bundled all my code in one single promise and that worked.

for example:

```
       function requestFromController(body){

           return new PromiseReturns(function (resolve, reject) {
                if(body){
                   reject(new StandardError({
                        status: 'Error',
                        message: "Not Found",
                        originalError: err,
                        code: 404
                    }));
                }

                db.model.find().then(x => {
                    resolve(x);
                })
          });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Check this out

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var StandardError = require("standard-error")

Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    throw new StandardError("Not Found", {code: 404})
}).catch(StandardError, function(e) {
    console.log('custom error caught');
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('generic caught');
})
```

Output:

```
$ custom error caught
```

Comment: You do see the difference between your code and the code in the question ... right?

Comment: I am using standard-error module. actually it should trigger righ catch

Comment: Why not `Promise.reject(new StandardError("Not Found", {code: 404})).then ...`